# mailing function in php

Tags: php

I am using php Mailing function in my project. i have sent the values in a php variable

Like

```
$myvalue="Universal Laser Systems®";
 $mailbody="<table><tr><td>".<?=$myvalue?>."</td></tr></table>";
```

But my email is showing

Univer! sal Laser Systems®

How i avoid such a special charector...........

Comment: @deceze, why did you edit the mistakes back in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the email header so that it can correctly handle your special characters.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UNICODE-1-1-UTF-8
```

Try that and see how you go.

You can see an example of setting the headers in the [manual found here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: still i have the same problrem.

Answer (score 0):

use a mail class, like Rmail

http://www.phpguru.org/static/mime.mail.html

makes it easyer and more likely to end up in a mailbox the way you want it.

Comment: Another nice mail class is [WaMailer](http://phpcodeur.net/wascripts/wamailer/). I really love it, but the documentation is in french...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phpmailer then use the SMTP class and include it and for html body use the Content-Type: text/html; charset=UNICODE-1-1-UTF-8